# SQL work with counting column meeting condition

Tags: sql

I have 20 column x1-x20.
For each row, I want to count how many columns having value >50.
It is kind of array processing but I don't know how to do it in SQL.
Can you please help?
Thank you,
HHC

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a solution involving programming a stored procedure, you just need to list each column out using CASE conditions as below:

```
select 
case when x1 > 50 then 1 else 0 end +
case when x2 > 50 then 1 else 0 end +
case when x3 > 50 then 1 else 0 end +
case when x4 > 50 then 1 else 0 end +
...
case when x20 > 50 then 1 else 0 end as cols_gt_50
from t
```

In plain SQL statements there's no way (that I know of) that you can treat column names as an array.